# Serve Java Spark static files at / with overlapping routes like /api/search

Tags: java, web-frameworks, spark-java

In the Java Spark framework, how can I serve static files (index.html, CSS, JS) at the root `/` with REST endpoints like `/api/search`?

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Spark.staticFiles.location("/");
    Spark.staticFiles.externalLocation("my-static-folder");
    Spark.get("/api/search", (req, res) -> "rest endpoint");
  }
```

With the example above, Spark won't use the `/api/search` endpoint.  Instead, it will serve `my-static-folder/api/search/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't need the `GET` on `/api/search`, I needed a `POST`.  Using a POST makes everything work as expected:

```java
Spark.post("/api/search", (req, res) -> "rest endpoint");
```

I'm not sure how to make the `GET` work.